# How do I view the actual Catalog URL on a fresh install of Magento?

Tags: magento

This is a silly simple question I’m sure, but since I’m new to Magento, I need to ask.

How on earth do I navigate to the catalog pages? 
I mean, I don’t have any links pointing that way via the homepage, but even if I type in a specific URL I can’t seem to bring it up…

for example, I can view specific products via this: 
 
http://luxuryoverload.com/catalog/product/view/id/2

but if I try to view the catalog via this:  
http://luxuryoverload.com/catalog/category/view/id/2

I just get a 404 page…

I have set up 3 root folders in the admin for “handbags”, “shoes”, “accesories” 
Those are my only & main categories.

I know this seems like a simple problem, but honestly I’m pulling my hair out just trying to figure this one out…

Any help would be much much appreciated…

-Abbey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root categories do not show directly. There should only be one per store (which you associate together in *System > Manage Stores*) and then put "handbags", "shoes" & "accessories" categories within that.

Comment: Correct, and then simply navigate to that page using it's name (ie. New Arrivals) in the admin + .html, so for example: http://www.luxuryoverload.com/new-arrivals.html
**Just thought I'd reply/answer this finally..